# In imaginary numbers how can this be correct that i^1=i and i^1 = -1?

Tags: complex-numbers

My problem is based on two arguments. As shown $i=-1$. This is in contradiction with $i^1 = i$. How can this be correct?

$$\begin{align}
i^4 & = i \cdot i^3 \\
& = i \cdot -i \\
& = -1 \cdot i \cdot i \\
& = -1 \cdot -1 \\
& = 1
\end{align}$$

Alternatively we can solve this problem as follow:

$$\begin{align}
i^4 & = i \cdot i^3 \\
& = i \cdot -1 \\
& = -i \\
\end{align}$$

Therefore we conclude that $-i = 1$ and therefore $i = -1$.

Comment: $i^4$ does indeed equal $1$. $i^3$ does not equal $-1$. $i^3 = -i$.

Comment: You even wrote on second line that $i^3=-i$. So why did you change your mind in the second part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$i^3$ is not $-1$. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$